# Could the gravitational field be a cloud of particles not curved spacetime?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity

The more I've been looking into quantum gravity the more I've been coming to the conclusion that the graviton must be some sort of particle within a cloud of identical particles surrounding massive objects. Is this an agreeable approach to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This was proposed and disproven hundreds of years ago. Clouds of particles cannot account for gravity quantitatively. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Sage%27s_theory_of_gravitation

Comment: I was thinking more of particles from the object tunneling to within what we refer to as the gravitational field of the object rather than free particles floating around in space. I have this idea that the graviton is the electron. If this were true it could clearly account for gravity quantitatively as the number of electrons in an object is proportional to mass.

Comment: Gravitons are definitely not electrons. Electrons have charge, mass, and spin 1/2. From analysis of gravitational waves the upper bound on the mass of the graviton is **29 orders of magnitude** smaller than the rest mass of an electron (not to mention charge and spin). It's always good to be thinking and curious about the world. But in order to advance our understanding of quantum gravity, a theory on the cutting edge of physics that has eluded the best and most knowledgeable minds of the past century, you'll need to master a good chunk of known physics first. Cheers!

Comment: Also the number of electrons in an object is *not* proportional to mass. The proton has no electrons yet is massive. Consider neutron stars, different isotopes of atoms, ions... Etc.

Comment: It should be noted that our understanding of what constitutes a mass first is determined by how an object interacts with other particles. Neutrinos interact very weakly and hence are considered to be less massive. The mass of the photon is an interesting case because we only consider it to have zero mass because we cannot measure that mass in tradition (classical) ways, or because it's a convenience. In the case of protons I'd suggest that even tha mass of the proton is determined by its electrical interactions with other particles.

Comment: That is not what constitutes mass. Mass is defined by resistance to acceleration or by gravitational attraction, the definitions agree experimentally as explained by the equivalence principle. What you've said contradicts special relativity as the photon travels at $c$ implying it is massless but it also interacts with charged particles. To improve physics, you must fully understand physics. It's like reading a synopsis of Shakespeare then critiquing the literary analysis of Shakespeare experts, further standing your ground in the face of contextual evidence contradicting you.

Comment: Well actually that is what constitutes mass. If a positively-charged particle is travelling through a field of negatively-charged particles it acquires a mass due to the extent to which its trajectory is altered due to the charge of the negative particles. The only way we have of determining mass is as a measure of how much force (from gravity) is acting on a particle.